# Javascript Background Image Changing Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the several background images of divs with the click of a button. I currently have a content slider and want to change the button  when a different button is clicked, I want the end result to be so that when your on the content of one dinosaur, that button will actually show a detailed picture of that one, opposed to the usual black silhouette which is yet to be drawn and implemented.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
                                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<title>Dinosaurs 4 Kids!</title>

<style>

</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor='black'>


<div id="contentContainer">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="itemOne" class="content">

        </div>
        <div id="itemTwo" class="content">

        </div>
        <div id="itemThree" class="content">

        </div>
        <div id="itemFour" class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="navLinks">
    <ul>
        <li class="itemLinks" id="b1" data-pos="0px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" id="b2" data-pos="-1250px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" id="b3" data-pos="-2500px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" id="b4" data-pos="-3750px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" id="b5" data-pos="-5000px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" id="b6" data-pos="-6250px"></li>
    </ul>
</div>



<script>
 // just querying the DOM...like a boss!
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".itemLinks");
var wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

// the activeLink provides a pointer to the currently displayed item
var activeLink = 0;

// setup the event listeners
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.addEventListener('click', setClickedItem, false);

    // identify the item for the activeLink
    link.itemID = i;
}

// set first item as active
links[activeLink].classList.add("active");

function setClickedItem(e) {
    removeActiveLinks();

    var clickedLink = e.target;
    activeLink = clickedLink.itemID;

    changePosition(clickedLink);
}

function removeActiveLinks() {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
}

// Handle changing the slider position as well as ensure
// the correct link is highlighted as being active
function changePosition(link) {
    link.classList.add("active");

    var position = link.getAttribute("data-pos");
    wrapper.style.left = position;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>


#wrapper {
    width: 5000px; 
    position: relative;
    left: 0px; 
    transition: left .5s ease-in-out;
}

.content {
    float: left; 
    width: 1250px;
    height: 600px;
    white-space: normal;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#itemOne {
    background-color: #ADFF2F;
    background-image: url(weekly-exchange-background-1-1.jpg);
}
#itemTwo {
    background-color: #FF7F50;
    background-image: url("http://www.kirupa.com/images/yellowSquare.png");
}
#itemThree {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    background-image: url("http://www.kirupa.com/images/pinkSquare.png");
}
#itemFour {
    background-color: #DC143C;
    background-image: url("http://www.kirupa.com/images/graySquare.png");
}

#contentContainer {
    width: 1250px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 3.5%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}
    #navLinks {
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            border:1px solid white;
    }
    #navLinks ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 6px;
    }
        #navLinks ul li {
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 10px;
            list-style: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: lightgray;
            padding: 90px;
            border-radius: 10%;
            border: white 5px solid;
        }
            #navLinks ul li:hover {
                background-color: #FFFF00;
            }
            #navLinks ul li.active {
                background-color: #333333;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                outline-width: 7px;
            }
                #navLinks ul li.active:hover {
                    background-color: #484848;
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                }
#navLinks ul li.active {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline-width: 7px;
}
#navLinks ul li.active:hover {
    background-color: #484848;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#b1 {
    background-image: url(adboxbannerjpg-09.jpg);

}
```

Comment: You explained what you want, but didn't mention anything about the problem you are having in doing it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please explain what your problem is. Why isn't that existing code working for you? A jsfiddle or code snippet always helps :)

Comment: I want to know how to change the background image of the buttons when i click on them